# What are the ways to use a LIST of features which are DYNAMIC (contents) in nature?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection, feature-engineering, recommender-system

Any features which is represented as a list of 0 or more elements is what I call a `Dynamic` feature.

Let us suppose an example where there are 10 Million movies and a User feature sample looks like:

```
   Age  Gender  County  Movies-Liked
1. 25   M       USA     [Movie-1934, Movie-135, Movie-13]
2. 12   F       UK      [Movie-1]
3. 63   M       IND     []
4. 34   F       UK      [Movie-135, Movie-1]
```

In this case the feature named `Movies-Liked` is a **Dynamic** feature.

Let's suppose there are 2 different tasks:

1. Merchandise (books, t-shirts etc) recommendation to user
2. User Classification

and I want to use `Movies-Liked` as a feature in both of them.

**What are all the ways to use that as a feature**?

Using `OHE` of all the movies separately is not an option at all because One Hot Encoding of 10 Million movies is not practically possible

Comment: What is your target variable in this exercise?

Comment: @jbowman Just curious, does the label affect the processing? Let's suppose it's 2 different tasks. 1. Merchandise (books, t-shirts etc) recommendation to user  2. Binary Classification given user data